# How to notify about changing property of ListBox item?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, mvvm-light

So, i have list of items (stored in ObservableCollection), how to notify about item's property change?

I have current solution: property is also rising NotifyPropertyChanged(), and it seems to work. However, sometimes, property is changed, but not notified to the view (debugger shows that private field contains new value, but screen shows still old one). Maybe it is better way for doing it?

EDIT1: yes, binding is done in TwoWay mode.

EDIT2: just figured out that sometimes PropertyChanged is null. Why it can be?

EDIT3: code is quite basic. I'm using the very common NotifyPropertyChanged()

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Setter:

```
public double Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return amount;
        }
        set
        {
            amount = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Amount");
        }
    }
```

Model is inherited (just found that it can be a problem)

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Changing amount:

```
var foundItem = shoppingList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ean == item.ean);
        if (foundItem != null)
        {
            foundItem.Amount += 1;
        }
```

List filling in the VM:

```
public class  MyViewModel : BaseFoodieViewModel
{
private ObservableCollection<ProductSearchCategoryCollection<Item>> _itemsList = new ObservableCollection<ProductSearchCategoryCollection<Item>>();
    public ObservableCollection<ProductSearchCategoryCollection<Item>> ItemsList
    {
        get { return _itemsList; }
        set { Set(() => ItemsList, ref _itemsList, value); }
    }

****


ItemsList.Clear();
            var list = from item in parsedList
                        group item by item.code
                        into it orderby it.Key
                        select new ProductSearchCategoryCollection<Item>(it.Key, it);

            ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<ProductSearchCategoryCollection<Item>>(list);
```

EDIT 4: just figured out, that it works for several items. Those items, which are unchanged - they are working fine. But when i'm starting to change it, at one moment, PropertyChanged is null.

EDIT 5: so, i just restarted project. Those items, which are already changed - they are still unnotifyable (PropertyChanged == null). However, the rest is working okay.

EDIT 6: so far, problem is in

```
var foundItem = shoppingList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ean == item.ean);
    if (foundItem != null)
    {
        foundItem.Amount += 1;
    }
```

Comment: post your code, otherwise its hard to help.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud Just added. Sometimes it works, but at the some moment, it just stops notifying. I guess, something causes PropertyChanged to be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with adding items.

It should be

```
var foundItem = shoppingList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ean == item.ean);
            if (foundItem != null)
            {
                foundItem.Amount += 1;
                item.Amount = foundItem.Amount;
            }
```

Now it sends notification. Compare it with Edit 6.

Thanks to user2399170, he made some useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Observable collection has event about changing collection of items (CollectionChanged). You should subscribe on it. When you see that new item is added, you need subscribe on it (onto PropertyChanged). And when it is removed from collection not forget to unsubscribe.

Comment: I assume, it is done by ObservableCollection and setter. Because basically it works. But at one moment, it just stops sending notification. The bad thing is that i still dont know whole algorithm, how to reproduce problem.

Comment: Where is the place of subscription?

Comment: ViewModel is inherited from MvvmLight's ViewModelBase, so i can use Set() => syntax. For the item i'm using pure NotifyPropertyChanged for now (in general, i dont want to inherit Model from ViewModelBase).

Comment: Ok 'Set' is clear. It is just field = value and then raise property changed. For me not clear, where you subscribe on items?

Comment: For me either, actually xD. If to talk seriously, i thought that ObservableCollection would catch it's items notifications and notify view about that. It works.. sometimes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30281/discussion-between-vitalii-vasylenko-and-user2399170)